# VirtualBox selected space never returned

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed a virtual machine (ubuntu) with virtualbox on windows10 and i selected 20gb to use it.
I have removed the virtual machine and the 20gb never returned to the total space of my hd. 
I have uninstalled the virtualbox and nothing.
someone knows how can i get back the lost space?

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox MOST probably created a virtual disk on your harddisk, which was containing the OS. When you removed the virtual machine, you were probably proposed the option to delete or not the associated virtual disks. If you didn't removed the virtual disks, they are still on your HDD. What you have to do is to locate when your virtual disk is and remove it.

On recent versions of VirtualBox, you have to go in the media manager where you will probably find your virtual HDD. Hovering over it will confirm you whether it is still attached to a VM or not. If not, you may safely delete the disk (not just remove it from the virtual media manager, but effectively deleting the disk. VirtualBox will ask you to confirm this).